# Saving the state of the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state, react-forms

I have two input text fields where I want to update them automatically using state. But whenever I uncheck the box, the value is disappearing. Once entered it should be there if I uncheck as well. If not, I cannot write two different values in the input text field.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Jsme } from "jsme-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { default as FormData } from "form-data";

export default function App() {
  // I added the following state variables to keep track of checkboxes
  const [isCheckbox1Checked, setIsCheckbox1Checked] = useState(false);
  const [isCheckbox2Checked, setIsCheckbox2Checked] = useState(false);
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const [syncToFirst, setSyncToFirst] = useState();
  const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState();
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      solute: "",
      solvent: ""
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Jsme
        height="300px"
        width="400px"
        options="oldlook,star"
        onChange={setSoluteState}
      />
      <h1>{solutestate}</h1>
      <input
        className="mr-2 leading-tight"
        type="checkbox"
        value={isCheckbox1Checked}
        onChange={() => setIsCheckbox1Checked(prev => !prev)}
      />
      <input
        className="mr-2 leading-tight"
        type="checkbox"
        value={isCheckbox2Checked}
        onChange={() => setIsCheckbox2Checked(prev => !prev)}
      />
      <form>
        <input
          {...register("solute")}
          placeholder="SOLUTE"
          onChange={(e) =>
            syncToFirst === 1
              ? setSoluteState(e.target.value)
              : setInput1(e.target.value)
          }
          value={isCheckbox1Checked ? solutestate : input1}
        />
        <input
          {...register("solvent")}
          placeholder="SOLVENT"
          onChange={(e) =>
            syncToFirst === 2
              ? setSoluteState(e.target.value)
              : input2(e.target.value)
          }
          value={isCheckbox2Checked ? solutestate : input2}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

need a handler to save the state when the text changes. so that if I uncheck the check box the previous state is present in the input field text. and whenever i try to type directly in the second input text field it is throwing an error as `input2 is not a function`. code sand box [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-darkness-c1yfq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I don't see function input2 for this statement: `input2(e.target.value)` Maybe you meant `setInput2(e.target.value)`

Comment: syncToFirst is `undefined` as its first value. Did you dry run what will happen if it is undefined?

Comment: @harsh yeah, its a typo for `input2`. However, your rest of the question makes very little sense on what you are trying to achieve. Please rephrase better so that people can answer `What is expected` and also include `What you have tried already`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `input2(e.target.value)` is not a function. Maybe you meant `setInput2(e.target.value)`.

Secondly you set the value of `syncToFirst` as `undefined`. So the statement

```
 syncToFirst === 1
      ? setSoluteState(e.target.value)
      : setInput1(e.target.value)
```

goes into the `else` or `:` part which set its value to `""` again as `e.target.value` is `""`. Hope that answers your question.

`Edit`:

Explaining further when the first checkbox is picked, the value of `syncToFirst` is 1. Now when you type something in the first checkbox, you call this method `setSoluteState` but the value of the input1 as a single source of truth is "". So when you uncheck this field, `syncToFirst` becomes 2. Now value become `input1` as you have given. But input1 is `""` so it becomes empty. The other text field however takes up the value of solute state and it goes up. Now when you type in the first input1 field, it will change its value.

This is expected behavior nothing off. You should work on your logic or DM me. Remember that in react the JSX part is re-rendered and the value field is calculated. Write it down and you'll see when actually the value of input1 and input2 are changing and what you are assigning in each re-render.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo error. and I didn't understand the `undefined` part here.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-darkness-c1yfq?file=/src/App.js u can check here what i am doing. after the text field gets its value from editor when unchecked the value is disappearing. I am doing prediction with both the text fields @Shobhit Tewari

Comment: I have given explanation in my answer as an edit. DM me after this. Logical mistake. Behavior is expected.